# Error trying to copy gz userdata file to partition in adb shell

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, images, scripts

Dealing with limited space I split my userdata image file with this command:

> dd if=/dev/block/mtd/by-name/userdata | gzip -c | split -b 250m - /mnt/sdcard/userdata.gz.

That works fine, but when I try to restore with this command:

> cat userdata.gz* | gzip -dc | dd of=/dev/block/mtd/by-name/userdata

I get this error:

> -dc: No such file or directory
>
> 0+0 records in
>
> 0+0 records out
>
> 0 bytes transferred in 0.001 secs (0 bytes/sec)

Yes,I shelled into the device and navigated to the directory I pushed the gz file to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: cat userdata.gz* | gzip -d > /dev/block/mtd/by-name/userdata

Comment: Yes.. This did it. Thank you!! I don't know how (or if I'm supposed) to mark this as the answer??